# How can I randomly scatter objects uniquely within diferent instances in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, collections, random

I made a procedural Overhead Sign Group Node. See .blend file below.

I have a collection of 5 blue panels which I distribute over the metal framework by creating a mesh line and points.

Now the order of the blue panels is the same for each individual framework. See images below.

How can I randomly distribute the blue panels on each framework in a different way?

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try taking a random number, modulo 6 (1 of 5 signs or none), socket index to the random seed, random integer to modulo, and modulo to selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will answer your question so I'll just post it as an answer so I can post a picture.

This will give you a random number per index you can use to pick a sign. I'm pretty sure if the index is out of bounds (6) it will not instance on that point.

[image]

As you can see I have a bunch of joined individual geometries and it picks from those.
[image]

Comment: Hi Haskell,
Thanks for your answer! I tried your method in the blender file, but I'm not able to make it work. (on your screenshot some values are hidden behind a pop-up info). 
It doesn't seem to change the order of the panels. Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Make sure pick instances is on. You can plug an integer in instead of index and change the values manually to see if it is making a selection.

Comment: I confirmed that it works. Modulo should plug into instance index not selection.

Comment: Thanks a lot Haskell, I managed to work out a solution that works using your technique: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wf5413qsszcfmv0/Screenshot%202023-01-25%20195859.png?dl=0 
I watched a video about the Modulo node, but I'm not quiet sure what it does here. Does the modulo node makes sure each of the 5 different panels is chosen in equal amounts?